# Hazelcast 3.3.3. No updates in EntryListener after cluster recovery

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast 3.3.3 (latest stable release) in the following configuration: 2-node cluster and 1 client.
Client puts tasks into IMap whereas nodes execute them and update corresponding map values once finish. Client gets notified via EntryListener (entryUpdated()) registered via map.addEntryListener().

The problem appears when I emulate network issues: "tcpkill -i lo port  or port ". Cluster state is automatically restored after I stop tcpkill. So far so good.
There are two ways out then (sometimes 1, sometimes 2):

1. Client puts next task into IMap and fails on intermediate step -
   hazelcast.getPartitionService().getPartition() return
   null. Always null (after minutes) until cluster+client restart.
2. Client puts next task into IMap and target node (key owner) handles
       it as before (updates IMap entry). Client doesn't get notification
       via EntryListener (entryUpdated()) until cluster+client restart.

I couldn't find anything suspicious in log (log4j.logger.com.hazelcast=debug is enabled).
Tried different intervals for tcpkill being enabled: larger and lower than cluster.max.no.heartbeat.seconds and cluster.max.no.master.confirmation.seconds. Behaviour is the same, seems they have no effect on issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, I found an answer to case-2. Looks to be **Hazelcast bug**.

I looked into the source code of two versions: **3.2.5** (as the one where I've encountered the issue first time) and **3.3.3**. And here is what I found.

There is **EventServiceImpl** class responsible for at least of storing/providing **EventRegistration**-s, subscriptions containing the ones dealing with maps updates. When a client side tells `map.addEntryListener(..)` that listener eventually appears in cluster **EventServiceImpl** as an **EventRegistration**.

When cluster node executes some map update **EventServiceImpl** iterates over its **EventRegistration**-s:

```
@Override
public void publishEvent(String serviceName, Collection<EventRegistration> registrations,
                         Object event, int orderKey) {

    ...
    for (EventRegistration registration : registrations) {
        ...
        Registration reg = (Registration) registration;
        if (isLocal(reg)) {
            executeLocal(serviceName, event, reg, orderKey); // EXECUTION GOES HERE
            continue;
        }

        if (eventData == null) {
            eventData = nodeEngine.toData(event);
        }
        EventPacket eventPacket = new EventPacket(registration.getId(), serviceName, eventData);
        sendEventPacket(registration.getSubscriber(), eventPacket, orderKey);
    }
}
```

and notifies interested parties. Registration associated with a client side subscription contains a reference to **ClientEndpoint** and eventually to **Connection** to send updates over.

When cluster encounters network issues (I used tcpkill to block communication between nodes) its state changes so that client disconnects. After tcpkill is stopped nodes successfully join cluster back
and client restores its connection. Both Hazelcast versions do not recognize this reconnection in the sense that **EventServiceImpl** stays unaware of changes. Behaviour differs depending on Hazelcast version:

- In **3.2.5** after recovery **EventServiceImpl** keeps knowing about stale **EventRegistration** (connection with a client is no longer alive). Notifications on map updates are not delivered because of this reason.
- In **3.3.3** stale **EventRegistration** is removed from the **EventServiceImpl**. But after client reconnects (automatically) his subscriptions are not restored.

Comment: To be sincere, I'm surprised to see no interest from Hazelcast team  here. Ok, here is defect report with step by step explanation: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4186